# adventureworks database for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Can anybody help me out with an issue I am having trying to setup the Adventureworks database to PostgreSQL.

I uploaded the database from Norfolk data science on github. I unzipped the files placed the Csv files and install.sql file in a folder on the c: driver but all I can access is the tables but not actual data for instance of I put

```
SELECT: businessentityid, name, salesperson 
FROM sales.store 
LIMIT 10;
```

it pulls 0 rows back. Any ideas?

I should probably add I followed the instructions from [datajoe.blog/2020/08/04/getting-started-with-postgresql](https://datajoe.blog/2020/08/04/getting-started-with-postgresql)

Comment: Sounds as if something went wrong when importing the data.  Without more details on how exactly you did it (just "placing" the files somewhere doesn't do anything) and which errors you got when you ran the script

Comment: hi so I unzipped the files and placed them in my c: drive with the install.sql in there to under update. I the in command created a adventureworks database and then psql -h localhost -d adventureworks - U postgres  -a  -f  c:\psdata\install.sql;  this then seemed to have run as it should have and start running threw numerous files fine. however when I then try and search the data all the tables are there plus schemas but no actual data in the tables

Comment: I dont get any error reports just when I search a table such as the one in the op comment It comes back with the relevant table but no rows of data

Comment: It looks like there are two steps, first executing the SQL to create the tables and possibly other objects, second importing the actual data into the created tables. Were both of these successful?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL script is expecting the CSV files to be in the ./data subdirectory so if they are in the same directory as the .SQL file the script can't find them.

To fix the problem, just create a c:\psdata\data subdirectory and copy the CSV files into it, empty the database or delete and create a new one, and run the script again.

I just tried it and it is working perfectly.